# Owl carousel (Canvas) autoplay working but speed not changing at all

Tags: jquery, carousel

I have owl carousel working within a Canvas template environment but the javascript connected to it doesn't seem to be functioning properly. The documentation refers to 'autoplay', and altering this number to change the delay between transitions.

Altering the number has no effect whatsoever. Can anyone assist? This is driving me mad. I know there are later versions of owl carousel out there that have slightly different documentation. I know some may say try 'autoPlay' with uppercase, but that stops it from working completely.

Current code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                    var ocClients = $("#oc-clients");


                    ocClients.owlCarousel({
                        margin: 0,
                        // loop: true,
                        // nav: false,
                        autoplay: 1000,
                        // speed: 600,
                        // paginationspeed: 1000,
                        // dots: false,
                        autoplayHoverPause: true,
                        responsive:{
                            0:{ items:3 },
                            600:{ items:4 },
                            1000:{ items:5 },
                            1200:{ items:6 },
                            1400:{ items:6 }
                        }
                    });

                });
```

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Docs of owl carousel 1 says autoPlay : integer would turn the delay to 5 seconds. If that's not working, please create a demo or provide some more code.

Comment: Yes, using autoPlay breaks it as I believe this version of owl carousel that Canvas provide, is an older version so only autoplay (in lowercase works). The site can be seen at blueprint.campaigncircle.co.uk and the logos are at the very base if this helps? It's the carousel at the very base of the index page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

autoplay: true,
autoplayTimeout: 1000,

Comment: Please add more details to the answer.